# How to fetch a public page's posts using facebook graph api?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can I fetch all the posts data from a page with logged in user's access token ? or Is there any other way to retrieve all the posts data of a public page using Facebook Graph Api for Android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get facebook post data in json format that you can parse according to your requirement.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                AccessToken.getAccessToken(),
                "/YOUR_PAGE_ID/posts",
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        // Insert your code here

                        Log.d("raw response ",response.getRawResponse());
                    }
                });

        request.executeAsync();
```